# getElementById returns null used in Content Pages

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am Using Master-Content page Scenario,master page is used only for Showing the Header. my whole Logic is On the Content page. I have used javascript for Validation , javascript function called on buttons onClientClick But getElementById returns Null

```
<input type="text" id="Text2" name="txtCustEmail" class="form-control input-group" placeholder="Email" style="width:75%;" runat="server" />
```

and Javascript Function is:

```
function valData() {
  debugger;

  var Email = document.getElementById("txtCustEmail").value;
  var telno = document.getElementById("txtTelno").value;
  var mob = document.getElementById("txtMob").value;
  if(Email=="") {
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}
```

and Button Click

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClientClick="return valData();" Width="15%" />
```

when I use this Same Logic on separate web Page, it is working but adding Master page reference its not Working.

Comment: Looks like someone needs to learn what the difference between an `id` and a `name` is …?

Comment: And that aspnet renames the ID's of controls when using a Master Page.

Comment: <input type="text" id="txtCustEmail" class="form-control input-group" placeholder="Email" style="width:75%;" runat="server" />       and  var Email =document.getElementById("#txtCustEmail").value;    Still Returns Null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HI Bhauso,**

```
Set property ClientIdMode="Static" in your controls.
Ex :- <input type="text" id="Text2" name="txtCustEmail" ClientIdMode="Static" class="form-control input-group" placeholder="Email" style="width:75%;" runat="server" />
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing between ids and names. `document.getElementById("#id")` expects an id not a name.

```
var Email = document.getElementById("#Text2").value;
```

Edit your other lines accordingly.

Also edit this line,

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClientClick="valData" Width="15%" />
```

Comment: you are right Sid24 ,but var Email =document.getElementById("#txtCustEmail").value;

Comment: <input type="text" id="txtCustEmail" class="form-control input-group" placeholder="Email" style="width:75%;" runat="server" />

Comment: but Still returns Null

Comment: Your question statement mentions the id as Text2 and not txtCustEmail. `<input type="text" id="Text2" name="txtCustEmail" class="form-control input-group" placeholder="Email" style="width:75%;" runat="server" />
`